# The chat Sleigh needs more rudolph

Tags: feature-request, chat

There is a disturbing lack of reindeer on the chat sleigh.

[image]

Comment: Gahh!! I **knew** I saw *something* flying across the screen yesterday...

Comment: Epic screen cap is epic.

Comment: More sleigh bell.

Comment: Do we want to end up [like this guy](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JzdY-ux-aCE)?

Comment: Definitely needs more me.

Comment: Rudolph is a scab reindeer

Comment: @random: Not a scab, the know-it-all consultant that the boss thinks will solve all the problems with the current project and who nobody wants to work with.

Comment: Rudolf?!? Screw that! We need a *unicorn* with glowing horn, damnit!

Comment: Maybe after christmas.

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's not Friday where you live.

Comment: Am I missing something? How do you have a cat on top of your avatar?

Comment: @AndyDwyer: Yes, you're missing something...

Answer (score 8):

It's clearly an elaborate sled, and not a sleigh. Thus, adding reindeer would be inappropriate.

Comment: I'm (mostly) joking. If balpha wants to add reindeer, that's up to him.